# Why Ampère’s Law holds for infinite currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-current

I'm reading Griffiths proof of Ampère’s Law and in that proof he needs to show that :

$$\oint \frac{(x - x^{'})}{\imath ^{3}}\mathbf J \cdot \mathbf {da^{'}} = 0 $$ where $$\imath = \sqrt {(x - x^{'})^2 + (y - y^{'})^2 + (z - z^{'})^2} $$

He makes the claim that if $\mathbf J$ is confined to finite space then $\mathbf J_{\mathrm{surface}} = 0$ and the integral indeed equals zero.

In the notes he writes :

> If J itself extends to infinity (as in the case of an infinite straight wire), the surface integral is still typically zero, though the analysis calls for greater care.

**My question is :**

Why is the surface integral still zero in the case where $\mathbf J$ itself extends to infinity ?

Comment: What page in Griffith and what edition?

Comment: @N.Steinle 4th edition Page 233

Comment: Yes I see the footnote on pg. 233. I think the extra care comes in from the fact that your surface must extend to infinity, which requires some more advanced machinery than what Griffiths presents. But if I were you I'd wait for a good answer from someone who knows more about this.

Comment: Also, when you have $\vec{J} \neq 0$ at infinity, there are edge effects one has to deal with I think.

Comment: @N.Steinle I guess no one in Physics SE knows the answer to this question..

Comment: patience is critical. I upvoted it to attract more attention. But I think my comments above give you several hints for what Griffith means.

Comment: Also, it will encourage others to answer if you share your thoughts on the matter in the question statement and explain your attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of infinitely thin currents  atleast  this can be shown easily

For an infinitely thin current in the z direction the current density function is

$\vec{J} = I_{0}\delta^2(x,y) \hat k$

Taking the divergence, of this gives zero

As $\frac{\partial \vec{J_{z}}}{\partial z}=0$

Which proves the result about its validity involving amperes law.

This can be generalised to any wire shape extending to infinity.

[How to determine if a given charge and current density function satisfy continuity equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/676302/how-to-determine-if-a-given-charge-and-current-density-function-satisfy-continui)

It's pretty intuitive, as zero divergence means zero spacial dependence, if it goes to infinity, there will  never be a point along the wire that has a different value of current

Comment: The question is not asking about whether Ampère's law holds;  it's asking about whether a specific integral used in this proof of Ampère's law actually vanishes.

Comment: Surely proving that for infinite currents the divergence is zero is also proving why this surface integral vanishes vanishes when J extends to infinity via divergence theorem

Answer (score -2):

Ampere's law is actually an integrated form, the base form is

$H = Qv \times \vec s$, where s is the radiant vector $S = 1 / \gamma \hat r^2$, and $\gamma = 4\pi_{SI} = 1_{cgs}$
.

When this is integrated over a string of flowing charges, you get the current around a loop thing = loop around a current.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?